# About Replacing Fragment not Working in Activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments

I wanted to implement a feed as a Fragment like Instagram, so I organized the entire activity into Linear layout and set the Fragment tag to match parent.
below are FeedActivity xml and Java code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/FeedContainer">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.example02.Fragment.FeedFragment"
        android:id="@+id/feedfrag"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DetailFeedFragment detailFeedFragment;
    FeedFragment feedFragment;
    Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rootfeed);
        feedFragment = (FeedFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.feedfrag);
        detailFeedFragment = new DetailFeedFragment();
        bundle = new Bundle();


    }

    public void DetailFeed(String username) {

        bundle.putString("username",username);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.FeedContainer,detailFeedFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

and below are fragments that are gonna use one is for outline of the feed and Another is the Fragment used to replace the previous Fragment if it was pressed.

```
boardRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnFeedItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, int position) {
                PostInfo item=boardRecyclerViewAdapter.getItem(position);
                FeedActivity activity=(FeedActivity)getActivity();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),item.getPublisher().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.DetailFeed(item.getPublisher());
            }
        });
```

just in case if you need more detail about my code I'll edit right away. so feel free to make comment[Feed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnTZ9.png)

It's the feed I'm talking about. it's a feed with three rows, and if you click one here, you're going to move on to the DetailFeed Fragment, and the listener seems to work, but It don't change, and the system shuts down.

below is the error

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.example02.Fragment.DetailFeedFragment.onViewCreated(DetailFeedFragment.java:86)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

below is the code about DetailFeedFragment

```
public class DetailFeedFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<PostInfo> imageDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private String userName;
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    ViewGroup rootView;
    String photoUrl;
    final DetailFeedFragment.BoardRecyclerViewAdapter boardRecyclerViewAdapter = new BoardRecyclerViewAdapter();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_feed, container, false);


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            userName = getArguments().getString("userId");

        }





        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(boardRecyclerViewAdapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);




        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {





        database.getReference().child("posts").orderByChild("publisher").equalTo(userName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                imageDTOs.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    PostInfo imageDTO = snapshot.getValue(PostInfo.class);
                    imageDTOs.add(imageDTO);
                }
                boardRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }

    class BoardRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


        public PostInfo getItem(int position) {
            return imageDTOs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_feed_list, parent, false);
            return new CustomViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(imageDTOs.get(position).getPhotoUrl()).into(((DetailFeedFragment.BoardRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder) holder).post_Image);
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(photoUrl).into(((DetailFeedFragment.BoardRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder) holder).profile_photo);
            ((DetailFeedFragment.BoardRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder) holder).userId.setText(userName);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return imageDTOs.size();
        }


        public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView profile_photo;
            public com.example.example02.View.SquareImageView post_Image;
            public TextView userId;
            public TextView image_time_posted;

            public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                profile_photo = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
                post_Image = view.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
                userId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
                image_time_posted = view.findViewById(R.id.image_time_posted);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

and xml about 'fragment_detail_feed' and 'fragment_detail_feed_list'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Activity.FeedActivity">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/detail_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
                app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="fightnyy"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_photo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.example.example02.View.SquareImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_below ="@id/relLayout1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/post_image"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/heartLayout"
                android:background="@color/white">


            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout2"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3 DAYS AGO"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/image_time_posted"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem seems like on getting the FirebaseDatabse reference in DetailFeedFragment. Do you mind to share the onViewCreated method of that fragment?

Comment: show us the code for this line exactly: onViewCreated(DetailFeedFragment.java:86)

Comment: The error shows, you are calling throuch a null object in DetailFeedFragment. Kindly post your DetailFeedFragment code.

Comment: Is this what you asked me to correct?